# Select date range, last 30 days

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to return only the last 30 days of a query and I am having no success. I tried dumbing it down to just pull anything > 12/31/2019 still no success.

```
sql_string = ('''SELECT ViewListInvoices.Department, 
            ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]
            FROM ViewListInvoices
            WHERE (((ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date] > (12/31/2019))
            ))''')

    sql_result = query(sql_string)
    shop_average_inv_last_month = sorted(sql_result)
    sql_result =[]
```

I have tried `> ('12/31/2019')` or `('#12/31/2019')` and quite a few others.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I feel so stupid there is no 31 days in December. if I put ('12/30/2019) it works. Can some one tell me how I can change it to pull only the last 30 days.

Comment: December do have 31 days.

Comment: Use `'YYYYMMDD'` as your date format - this works with all language and regional settings - and **yes**, December **does have** 31 days, so you can use `> '20191231'` and should get the desired results

Comment: Parameterize your query and you will not have to deal with mistakes like this. Presumably you will replace that literal with something that is determined at run-time in your application. At that point, your code has a sql-injection vulnerability without parameterization. And for pete's sake stop adding sets of parentheses for no particular reason.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will try it. And yes the fixed date will be determined at run time. As per the ((( this is what some one told me I had to do for ms SQL. Like I said I am still new to Python and still learning. Again thank you.

Comment: Thanks this worked , And thank you for the () comment. It works fine with out.

Comment: I like using `DATEFROMPARTS(2019,12,31)` because I know that it will return a date exactly as I meant it to be :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct syntax for a date constant:

```
ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date] > '20191231'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the `DATEFROMPARTS` function to Create a Date Literal**

I like using the [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to create a date literals in TSQL. This does require SQL Server 2012 or greater (which should not be a problem for most people).

While it may take a second or two longer to type this function, once it is there I find the code more readable and I do not have to worry about language and date format settings (e.g. look at this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe)).

Here is how your assignment should look (I removed a lot of the paretheses):

```
sql_string = ('''SELECT ViewListInvoices.Department, 
            ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]
            FROM ViewListInvoices
            WHERE ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date] > DATEFROMPARTS(2019,12,31) 
            ''')
```

---

Some people like relying on an implicit conversion of a string to date like Gordon demonstrates (very common in TSQL).

I have also seen some people use the [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function (especially pre-2012 SQL Sever).

```
sql_string = ('''SELECT ViewListInvoices.Department, 
            ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]
            FROM ViewListInvoices
            WHERE ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date] >  CAST(''20191231'' AS DATE)''')
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want the last 30 days from the last invoice date, use max subquery and dateadd

```
 SELECT ViewListInvoices.Department, 
        ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]
        FROM ViewListInvoices
        where ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]>=
        DateAdd(d,-30,
        (
        SELECT max(ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]) max_date
        FROM ViewListInvoices invoice2
        ))
```

or if you want all dates greater than 12/31/2019 use a string which will automatically convert to a cast('12/31/2019' as date)

```
  SELECT ViewListInvoices.Department, 
        ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]
        FROM ViewListInvoices
        where ViewListInvoices.[Invoice Date]>= '12/31/2019'
```